# cant upgrade by sudo apt- get upgrade, hash sum mismatch, ubuntu 16.04, problem upgrading firefox

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, firefox

```
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libxatracker2 amd64 17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 [1,106 kB]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libxatracker2 amd64 17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 firefox amd64 57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.16.04.5 [43.6 MB]
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 firefox amd64 57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.16.04.5
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 88.4 MB in 3min 20s (441 kB/s)                                         
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.16.04.5_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libxatracker2_17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb  Hash Sum 

mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: thank you @NOrbert  for your response, i have tried this i get hash sum mismatch,
'E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_57.0+build4-0ubuntu0.16.04.5_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libxatracker2_17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?'

Comment: You can change the mirror  from *Software & updates* to the nearest.

Comment: i changed the mirror to nearest and it worked! Thanks